# Increasing ETH balance of a contract on deployment

Tags: contract-development, balances

I am building an exchange where you can buy and sell tokens.

I have a contract `Exchange`. It contains a function `sellTokens` which will take the amount of tokens entered by a user and give them a corresponding amount of ether.

However, when the contract is initiated, it will always have a balance of 0 ether until `buyTokens` function is executed and the contract is funded with some ethereum.

Question: What is the best way to fund this contract on creation? Does this have to be done manually after the contract has been deployed or is it possible to automate this in the constructor?

Please let me know if I can provide any more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate this process adding `payable` keyword to constructor and implement. So, when you deploy smart contract you funds it with some ether from your balance.
However, I suggest you to implement a function whenever you want to funds in a particular situation your smart contract accessible only to smart contract owner.

You can see an example of smart contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract FundsSmartContract {
    address owner;

    constructor() payable {
        owner = msg.sender;
        // your logic
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "You aren't smart contract owner!");
        _;
    }

    // Check address about smart contract
    function funds(uint _amount) public payable onlyOwner {
        // your logic
    }

    // Check address about smart contract
    function getBalanceSmartContract() external view returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

NOTE: If you're using Remix IDE to test it, remember to set into `VALUE` textbox the amount of ether when you'll call payable functions.

Answer (score 0):

Other than making a constructor `payable`. You can also add the `receive` function which would allow you to fund the contract at a later stage, and could also save you from many security vulnerabilities if used right.